# Woocommerce Payment gateways on Shopping cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment, cart, gateway

I would like to move Payment options from Checkout to Shopping Cart.
User selects Shipping and Payment options directly on the Shopping Cart. Is it possible?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Means You dont want the checkout process in woocommerce.
Without checkout you want in cart it shows payment option.
For that u want to used some action and filter for the Woocommerce.
http://docs.woothemes.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/